# How to guarantee fairness among multiple users using amazon SQS queue?

Tags: architecture, message-queue, amazon-sqs

So I have a sqs queue that takes messages from producer.
each message can belong to different owner.

Suppose user A comes in and send 1000 messages to producer, which then put onto the queue. Now user B comes with only 1 message. He has to wait until consumer process all 1000 from user A.

How can I make it so that user B with 1 message has about the same chance as user A to be processed next by the consumer?

I thought of creating a queue for every user in the system, but that would mean to read from every one of them every time when doing polling, which is costly.

I'm not looking to have absolute fairness, approximately fair is enough.

Comment: You only have a single consumer?

Comment: i have 1 consumer, which runs on ~10 ec2 instances at the same time.

Comment: I would say that's ~10 consumers, no?

Comment: still new to sqs thing, so yea i guess 10 consumers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this sort of issue is with a form of throttling/rationing, where requests beyond the ration are classified as "overflow".

I've discussed this strategy before as an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34868028/836214) (worth a read), but it might be easier to explain with an example based on your specific use case:

1. User A submits 1000 messages at once. 10 of those messages go to your "main" queue, the remaining 990 go to an "overflow" queue.

   - For sending messages, you provide one interface - the implementation of which sends incoming messages to either 'main' or 'overflow' depending on how many messages that user has sent in the last X seconds.
2. User B submits 1 message - it goes to the main queue
3. User B's single message will be processed before the majority of User A's messages.

   - "Overflow" queue processing happens on a reduced frequency compared to the "main" queue (or only when main queue is empty)

This will give you rough fairness between users (everybody gets a limited slice of the main queue), and overflow queue provides "eventual processing" for all the requests.

Depending on the volume of messages, you may want to consider multiple layers of overflow queues to handle "ridiculously high" volume differently from "kinda high" volume users.

Comment: For anyone wondering on how to implement this processing of the overflow queue with reduced frequency you can use weighted round-robin. But if your requirements are like mine: To give a priority to overflow queue when main queue is relatively empty you can use a load-aware weighted round-robin (LAWRR). To learn how to implement it correctly you can use a paper with the title "A load-aware weighted round-robin algorithm
for IEEE 802.16 networks" by Ibrahim Saidu, Shamala Subramaniam, Azmi Jaafar and Zuriati Ahmad Zukarnain. NOTE: You can multiply the load of main by a factor you want  like 10.