# How to process messages from SQS queues by groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, aws-serverless

I currently have a SQS queue that triggers a lambda function, but SQS have a 120k limit on in-flight messages, meaning that only 120k messages can be processed by the lambda consumer. That works fine for the most case. But imagine I have clients A and B, if A sends 500k to the queue and after that B sends only 1 message, B needs to wait all messages in the queue to be processed. It does not make sense to create one queue for each client (at least not manually). How can I, for example, process messages from clients in a round-robin manner, give everyone the same time to process their tasks?

I have been looking into Kinesis data stream, but not so sure if this will solve my problem. Would I need to create an SNS that redirects to a lambda responsible to round-robin the message to queues that do the same thing but this way I would avoid sending client B to same queue as client A?

Comment: Generally you *would* create a queue per client.  In a Lambda environment you would have a separate Lambda definition triggered by the queue so that only the client that produces many messages would be slowed down.

Comment: In the scenario you mentioned, why should client B's message be processed before client A's messages, given that client A sent them all earlier? If you're trying to implement round-robin among multiple clients then you'd typically use one queue per client. The alternative is some kind of [per-client throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076373/how-to-guarantee-fairness-among-multiple-users-using-amazon-sqs-queue). May also be worth searching for other ideas of [message queue fairness](https://www.google.com/search?q=message+queue+fairness).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod, I think my question is a duplicated of [per-client throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076373/how-to-guarantee-fairness-among-multiple-users-using-amazon-sqs-queue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out SQS Fifo Queues. Fifo Queues have a concept of grouping using the group Id attribute. all messages in one group are processed in order. The limitations are you can only process one message per group at any given moment.

The above concept is the same as having one queue per tenant, just using one dedicated Queue.

#### Refer to the AWS Docs

> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/solving-complex-ordering-challenges-with-amazon-sqs-fifo-queues/

#### Article on ordering inside SQS

> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/solving-complex-ordering-challenges-with-amazon-sqs-fifo-queues/

##### Note:

FIFO queues are more expensive than standard queues, please refer to the pricing guide before making any decisions.

Comment: The limited throughput on FIFO queues might preclude this option. From [Amazon SQS FAQs | Message Queuing Service | AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/): _"FIFO queues support up to 3,000 messages per second. If you require higher throughput, you can enable high throughput mode for FIFO on the Amazon SQS console, which will support up to 30,000 messages per second."_ They also have a limit of 20,000 in-flight messages.

Comment: SQS FIFO using this message group id is what we use today but if you have a large backlog of the same group id it might take a long time for the queue to process a message from another group id that was in the backlog too, since it look only for the 20k oldest messages. But this was a good advice nevertheless.

Comment: why not explore Kafka, this isn't as managed as SQS but if you are looking for throughput and flexibility it will be the best approach. you can create your consumer to round-robin through the topics. each tenant can have a dedicated topic. @DanielDosSantosPereira

Comment: I have designed it using two queues (main and overflow queue) both with different weights but I am using a load-aware weighted round robin so in times when the load in overflow queue is very high it will have a priority over main. I do not know kafka yet but I intend to learn it in a near future. But for now, those two queues with SQS will work fine. Thanks for your advice @Nick.