# How to implement fair scheduling between multiple tennants writing to 1 stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-pulsar

As of now I have single Kafka Topic with 10 partitions. We have 10000 clients who keep dumping uncontrolled data into streams. The problem currently is that

1. A tenant with out any notice (or little notice) floods the topic
2. now the messages from other tenants suffer --> because their messages (handful) are queued behind and will take several hours to get their turn for processing

Question:

1. Can I somehow read may be 1k messages per tenant and roundrobin --> essentially like fair scheduling of Hadoop yarn
2. Can Apache pulsar help me in this? If yes then is there any example you can point me to?

I went through: https://www.confluent.io/blog/prioritize-messages-in-kafka/ already; but given the volume of clients it may not be practical to have 100k partitions etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not aware of any way to get what you want out of the box. You could probably have the consumer pause some partitions to prioritize consumption from the ones with more messages (for example, by checking the lag per partition after every few poll iterations).
2. I'm not familiar enough with Apache Pulsar to have a clear answer.

Comment: The problem i see with this approach --if i have 10k different tenants who produce the messages, each topic may have 1000 tenants and it may not be practical to traverse the queue to load balance between the tenants.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem: a single customer can monopolize the resources and delay execution from all other customers, just because their events arrived first.

On a different application with a low amount of messages, we just load all the events in memory, creating a in-memory queue for every customer and then dequeuing up to N events from each customer queue and re-queue them again into a different queue, lets call it the re-ordered queue. The re-ordered queue has a capacity limit. (lets say...100*N), so no additional elements are queue until there is space. This guarantees equal treatment to all customers.

I am facing the same problem now with an application that processes billions of messages. The solution above is impossible; there is just not enough RAM. We can't keep all the data in memory. Creating a topic for each customer also sounds overkill; specially if you have a variable set of active customers at any given point in time. Nevertheless, Pulsar seems to handle well thousands, even millions, of topics.

So the technique above may work well for you (and for me).
Just read from thousands of topics... write to another topic a limited number of messages and then wait for it to have "space" to continue enqueuing.

Comment: In pulsar also, if one topic has 1M messages enqueued and after 1minute if another topic gets just 1000; wouldnt the 1M topic useup all the resouces before the 1000msgs topic gets its share?

Comment: The current solution in hand we have (proven to scale to 1M msgs/sec in benchmarkings) is to enqueue msgs in RockDB on EBS disk and keep round robin-ing between the tenants picking up the oldest 100/ 1000 in each tenant always.

Comment: Could you describe more your solution ? Is that what you are intending to replace? The server hosting RockDB becomes a single point of failure.  I have used a similar solution in the past, but using MongoDB. It had the disadvantage that my database was the busiest when there was nothing to process, as all clients were constantly polling. We solved it by preloading a portion of the queue for the following polling requests, if not consumed we TTLed it, in case other tenants had added requests. Perhaps something similar can be achieved with more scalability and resiliency using a lakehouse table.

Comment: NO, we use RockDB via a java program. So what we do is, every 5 minutes we stop processing and sync the entire rock DB to the s3 (takes 500 milliseconds). The Rock DB also has the last Kafka offset synced to it. Meaning in case of a crash, all we have to do is sync the Rock DB from s3 to EC2 and read Kafka from the offset stored in RockDb. On the negative side, you might reprocess the last 5 minutes' data once again, on crash -- which is ok. As Kafka is at least once delivery and downstream systems are idempotent. Between, AWS Ec2 the crashes are as low as 1 in 2 years.

Comment: as a rule of thumb, I stay away from Mongo Db. I had never seen Mongo as performant as HBase --even for simple use cases like find by id.